# How to access values of two keys in the map lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list of dictionary like below :

```
    sample = [{'By': {'email': 'xyz@stackoverflow.com', 'name': 'xyzzy', 'id': '5859'}},{'By': {'email': 'abc@stackoverflow.com', 'name': 'abccb', 'id': '9843'}},
{'By': {'email': 'xyz@stackoverflow.com', 'name': 'xyzzy', 'id': '5859'}}]
```

From this, I am trying to access keys 'name' and 'id' and write distinct values into a dictionary.
Below is returning id's alone :

```
print(set(map(lambda x: x['By']['id'], sample)))
```

**output**: {'9843', '5859'}

**Required output** : {"9843":"abccb", "5859":"xyzzy"}

I tried with f-string to concatenate the 'id' and 'name' values with a colon (:) in between to give in the format "id:name" for each dictionary item in the list.

```
set(map(lambda x: f"{x['By']['id']}:{x['By']['name']}", sample))
```

**output** : {'9843:abccb', '5859:xyzzy'}

Is it possible to access values of two keys in the map lambda function ? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to create a dictionary from a list, you can use dictionary comprehension: `{x['By']['id']: x['By']['name'] for x in sample}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `dict`, not a `set`. You can get all the values in the `lambda` and pack them in a `tuple`

```
print(dict(map(lambda x: (x['By']['id'], x['By']['name']), sample)))
```

You should also consider a simpler solution, you don't really need `map` and `lambda` here, dict-comprehensions will do just fine

```
print({x['By']['id']: x['By']['name'] for x in sample})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing a set of strings, not a `dict`. Instead, use

```
{x['id']: x['name'] for x in sample for y in x['By']}
```

If you really want to continue using `map`, have the function return id/name tuples to pass to `dict`:

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x['By']['id'], x['By']['name']), sample))
```